# Нынче и надысь...

Tags: общие-вопросы

Вперёд полиглоты....откель взялось "нынче"( сегодня, сейчас) и откель "надысь"(тогда-когда было))

Comment: Откель у нас взялось "откель"? Что это за слово, @Ваня?

Comment: откель - то есть откуда, так моя бабушка говорила (Курская губерния)

Comment: "Отсель (откель?) грозить мы будем шведу, Здесь будет город заложён На зло надменному соседу..." (Видимо, и Пётр Великий так говорил)

Answer (score 2):

НЫНЧЕ. "Нынче ветрено и волны с перехлестом.Скоро осень, все изменится в округе" (И. Бродский).

Нынче - это просторечное "ныне". А вот у слова "ныне" интересная история. Оно соотносится с общеславянским вариантом nune (индоевропейский корень nu), и имеет значение "сейчас, теперь".  Сравнить: латышск.nu, греч. non, нем. nun, лат. ninc с тем же значением.  У Шанского "ныне" - это удвоение "но", значение "именно сейчас". (Таким образом, союз "но" из этой же семьи).

НАДЫСЬ. "Старуха-то жива. Надысь в церкви была" (Л. Толстой).

В толковых словарях НАДЫСЬ - это "совсем недавно, намедни", также "незадолго, считая не часами, а днями. 
ИЗ ИНТЕРНЕТА (надысь и др. слова): НАМЕДНИ - оными днями, но речь идёт о конкретном дне в недавнем прошлом. Например, намедни (во вторник).
НАДЫСЬ - просто иными днями, менее конкретно. Например, в начале неделе, но   день не указывается.
ДАВЕЧА - это в тот же день ранее. Давеча (с утра во вторник).